# The densest way to pack a box in $\mathbb R^n$ using $k$ points.

Tags: geometry

Suppose you are given a box in $\mathbb R^n$:

$B = I_1 \times I_2 \times ... \times I_n, \forall i,$ $I_i$ is a segment in $\mathbb R$.

You are also given $k$ points to place inside the box $p_1,...p_k$. What would be the optimal placement of the points in order for them to be as dense as possible, that is to minimize the maximal distance between each point in a box and the nearest point of the $k$-set? Formally, to find the placement that would achieve: 
$$ \min_{placement}\max_{x \in B} \min_{i \in \{1,2,...,k\}}dist(x,p_i)$$

I am almost sure that this is a known thing, but can not seem the proper term.

Comment: Unless some of the points already have predetermined locations that you cannot change, what is to stop you from taking any arrangement of the points and linearly shrinking it as much as you want? It seems you can easily make any arrangement denser. The more difficult question is how to make it _less_ dense. Are you sure that's not what you meant to ask?

Comment: @DavidK But I don't want to minimize the distance between the $k$ points. I want to minimize the the distance between $any$ point in $B$ and it's nearest neighbor out of the $k$ points. In your example, if we put all the points densely into one "corner" of the box, then the distance between the opposing "corner" to any of the $k$ points will be very great.

Comment: Sorry, the words "as dense as possible" confused me. The density of points in the box as a whole is $k/|B|$, which is fixed, so I started thinking of a more local definition of density. I might rather say you want to place $k$ points so as to make their "density" as uniform as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your minimum distance is $2r$ then you can fit spheres of radius $r$ round all your points so the spheres do not overlap. The spheres extend at most a distance $r$ outside the original box, so fit within a larger box whose sides are distance $r$ from the original.

If you can fit spheres into the larger box, you have found the points you need in the smaller one.

So you need to be looking at sphere packing.

Comment: But how would I know what $r$ is? Also, unless I am mistaken, sphere packing is "fit as many as you can, with a given radius", whereas I am given an exact quantity. I may be wrong on that account, though, I don't have much experience in the area.

Comment: @Aahz Sphere packing problems are difficult. But, for example, if you know the densest packing of seven circles in a unit square you can scale the configuration to fit seven points into an arbitrary square. Or if you know the smallest cube into which you can fit 25 unit spheres, you can scale the problem to fit 25 points into an arbitrary cube.

Comment: The shape of the gaps (the space not occupied by spheres) also matters, because the measurement you end up with is the distance from one of the points in that space to one of the $k$ points in the arrangement. It isn't obvious to me that an optimal sphere packing must necessarily scale to an optimal arrangement for OP's purpose.